# Push Notification in Windows App - How can I change the content of the Toast Message?

Tags: windows, cordova, push-notification, wns

I have a Windows App developed with Cordova. I registered it with my Windows Developer Account and got my token etc. Now when I send a push message (toast) via Fiddler to the App, which is currently installed on an Windows Phone 8.1, I receive the Notification on the Phone just fine - but it only says 'New Notification'.

I used this xml for the message:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <wp:Notification xmlns:wp="WPNotification">
        <wp:Toast>
            <wp:Text1>Test Message</wp:Text1>
            <wp:Text2>XXX</wp:Text2>
        </wp:Toast>
    </wp:Notification>
```

However, neither Text1 nor Text2 show up in my notification. 
How can I implement the toast notification to actually use the content from the push notification?

Since my application is written in Angular JS, I can not use any C# documentations on the topic.

Any help with this problem would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the MPNS format for toasts, but trying to push using WNS (I assume). Make sure you use the WNS toast format, documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465448.aspx). Your toast should be formatted something like this:

```
<toast>
    <visual>
        <binding template="ToastText02">
            <text id="1">Test Message</text>
            <text id="2">XXX</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>
</toast>
```

Comment: Yes, that was my sole problem. I did not realise there was a difference regarding the formats. Thank you very much!